# what is the difference between Text Service and Input method Editor?

Tags: windows-8, text-services-framework

I'm new to Windows8 Metro app development and Text Service and Input method Editor both are similar or not ,i am not understand the difference. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Text Services Framework (TSF) and a Input Method Edition (IME) work together with TSF processing the input supplies by the IME.

There is a very good overview of IMEs in Windows 8 at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848069(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Hi Marc ,Thank u very much for sharing information,in this reply-> TFS I think this is the grammar mistake.